# Как выглядит "куча имен" в sql?

Tags: mysql, sql

Привет.

Вопрос по `sql`. Не понимаю структуру, с которой имею дело.Если взять `PHP` или `JavaScript`, то у них есть "куча имен" и "куча значений". Эти кучи могут быть как локальные (код внутри функции), так и глобальные (глобальный код). "куча имен"в `PHP` реально в виде кучи и выглядит (все пользовательские переменные и функции в корне лежат, там же в корне лежат серверные массивы), "куча имен" в `JavaScript` имеет структуру дерева (дерева `BOM`, в которое входят деревья `DOM` и `CSSOM`). У меня есть программа-скрипт и связанная с ней "куча имен", откуда интерпретатор (`PHP` или `JavaScript`) берет имена переменных и функций (в джаваскрипте интерпретатор имена переменных и функций перед выполнением скрипта запихивает в объект-контекст выполнения кода). Как выглядит "куча имен" для `sql`? Можно ли в sql объявлять пользовательские функции? Циклы делать?

Comment: Пользовательские функции в sql - это sql процедуры

Comment: Это называется *пространство* имён. Насчёт PHP вы неправы. Функции и классы имеют свои собственные scope. Глобальное пространство это как бы нулевой уровень, а дополнительные уровни можно вводить с помощью namespace.

Comment: Если вы изучаете SQL то до момента когда будете свободно владеть запросами (с большой вложенность подзапросов и т.п.) забудьте про функции и циклы. SQL не относится к императивным языкам программирования. У него нет понятия "текущая инструкция", следовательно нет и необходимости в неких циклах, которые позволили бы эту "инструкцию" многократно выполнять. После того как будете хорошо понимать запросы, тогда можете начать изучать различные расширения (которые уже не sql) конкретных СУБД и в которых уже есть и инструкции и циклы и функции. Циклы и т.п. реально нужны менее чем 1% задач

Answer (score 3):

SQL - это язык запросов. Т.е. как таковой "кучи имен" (жесть термин) тут нет, а есть схема. Схема хранится в самой базе данных, в служебных таблицах.

У разных производителей баз данных существуют "надстройки" над стандартным SQL, например TSQL в MSSQL, PL/SQL в Oracle и т.д., позволяющие писать хранимые процедуры и, в некоторой степени, оперировать псевдопеременными в самих запросах. Тут важно понимать, что все эти "переменные" существуют только в рамках одной SQL-транзакции, внутри движка БД.

Возможно вам будет более понятна такая аналогия: У вас есть POST-запрос, в котором есть некий набор передаваемых данных ключ-значение и некоторое количество служебной информации. Самому этому запросу ничего не известно про то, что у него внутри и как его надо обрабатывать - он просто служит оберткой при общении клиент-сервер. Вот с SQL - та же самая история.

Что касается пространства имен. В контексте базы под этим термином можно рассматривать 2 различные сущности:

1) Имена таблиц, столбцов, встроенных процедур, индексов, ключей и т.д.
Это то, что принято называть "схема базы данных". Информация по ним хранится в служебных областях(таблицах) базы. У каждого производителя БД они свои. Как правило, извлечь эту информацию можно простым SQL-запросам к этим таблицам.

2) Переменные, используемые в хранимых процедурах и запросах(в диалектах, где это возможно). Данные переменные существуют только в рамках транзакции и область видимости у них всегда локальная. Т.е. переменные используемые в хранимой процедуре доступны только внутри этой процедуры. "псевдопеременные", используемые в запросе видны только на уровне этого запроса и не видны, например, внутри процедуры, вызываемой этим запросом(если их, конечно, не передали в них параметром **по значению**).

Еще раз хочу заметить, что второй тип - переменные в хранимках и запросах - это все "расширение" синтаксиса SQL, сильно зависящие от используемой БД. Они не входят в спецификацию SQL.

Comment: под кучей имен я подразумеваю пространство имен

Comment: @Dimon Термин пространства имен не применим. В запросе видны только те поля тех таблиц, которые указаны в запросе. Хотя с другой стороны некое пространство есть, например в корелированном подзапросе доступны "имена" как из таблиц подзапроса, так и из внешнего запроса. И в большинстве СУБД это правило действует только на 1 уровень вглубь. Т.е. нам уже не досупны имена самого внешнего уровня из подзапроса, находящегося в другом подзапросе.

Comment: @Dimon обновил ответ